# ASP.NET Popup rdlc chart when clicked

Tags: asp.net, charts, webforms, rdlc

I have a website with reportviewer displaying rdlc report that contain charts, I want to popup the chart that been clicked, is it possible ??

please guide me to the right way.

BR

Answer (score 1):

The reportviewer generates HTML and CSS code. Maybe you could try to search using Jquery the id of the graph that you want to show and associate the click event. But it may not work, another option is to try this product https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejreportviewer. It is a display that generates and supports HTML5 and Javascript RDLC, it may be more customizable.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded their product and working on it, it's really worth.